# Getting error message as Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd'

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I am trying to deploy a Mule app on Mule standalone 3.8.1, but I am getting this error message:

```
Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

It works fine when running from Anypoint Studio using Mule server 3.8.2 EE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataWeave is an enterprise feature, you can't use it when you deploy to a CE runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven , please add maven dependency for dataweave.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.weave</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-plugin-weave</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what is the mule version used in pom?

Comment: mule version is 3.8.2

Comment: I think you should change mule version in pom to 3.8.1 if you are trying to deploy it on 3.8.1.  I don't think 3.8.1 run time support upper version for dependencies, as dependency scope is provided not compile.

Answer (score 1):

The standalone Mule runtime must also be an EE version for DataWeave to work. Is your 3.8.1 an EE version?

Comment: I am deploying on Mule runtime 3.8.1 CE. is there any problem with that? When I changed runtime version to Mule Sever 3.8.1 CE in anypoint studio then it doesn't show Transform Message filter in Mule palette.

Comment: DataWeave is only available in Enterprise (EE) versions of the Mule Runtime. You won't be able to use it in CE.